# Getting data from textbox into array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

How to stream data entered by the user in text box into `int` array? Let's say, that I've got a window with 2 text boxes and buttons and buffer, that is not visible in interface.
I want data from `textbox1` (for example `CAT`) to be saved into `int buffer[255]` after clicking `button1`. Then, after clicking `button2`, '`CAT`' should appear in `textbox2` and being deleting from `buffer`.
It should be like:

```
int buffer[255]={0};
//user entered 'CAT' in textbox1
//clicking button1
//now:
buffer[0]=[67]; //67 = 'C' in ASCII
buffer[1]=[65];
buffer[2]=[84];
//clicking button2
//in read-only textbox2 'CAT' appears
//now:
buffer[]={0};
```

I guess there will be need some conversion while displaying word in textbox2 (`for loop` with `System.Convert.ToChar(buffer[i])`), but what puzzles me most is how to save text from `textbox1` into `buffer`.

Ok, thx for responses, now I need to make my button work, but don't know why, I've got now this method:

```
public int saveToBuffer(string text)
        {
            string txt = text;
            int[] receivedBuffer = new int[255];
            int count = 0;
            //int i = 0;

            foreach(char c in txt)
            {
                receivedBuffer[count] = c;
                count++;
            }
            return receivedBuffer[255];
        }
```

Which returns text from `textbox1` to array `receivedBuffer`. I also got this button:

```
private void saveToBufferButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

and I don't know what to put beetwen `{}` to make it work.

Comment: You could loop through `textbox1.Text` till the `textbox1.Text.Length` and get each char into buffer index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great response from Rob Epsteing, just to add a different approach without LINQ that might give an good idea of what we is essentially shown by Rob Epstein in 2 statements.

```
        string text = "CAT";
        int[] buffer = new int[text.Length];
        int count = 0;
        //add to buffer
        foreach(char c in text)
        {
            buffer[count] = c;
            count++;
        }

        //from buffer to text
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in buffer)
        {
            builder.Append(c);
        }
        text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Appreciating that I'm not using a statically defined buffer in this example, hopefully this will help you get to the desired solution:

```
int[] buffer = "CAT".Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();
string result = new string(buffer.Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray());
```

Replace "CAT" in the sample above with textbox1.Text.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method to retrieve ASCII code from string is :

```
string value = textbox1.Text;

// Convert the string into a byte[].
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```